# form in two different tabs

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm not sure if this is possible.

I have a site with a form, when clicking it opens a new tab:

```
 <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="second.html" target="_blank">
     <a class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="form.submit();">button 1</a>
 </form>
```

when clicking it opens a tab and show "second.html"

```
 <form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" >
      <textarea name="textArea2" id="textArea2"></textarea> 
     <a class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="form.submit();">return to first page</a>
 </form>
```

I would like, this second button return the textarea value to first tab.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible with a server side language. And get the value in the posted textArea2 variable

Comment: I'm using jsp, how can I do it?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm

Comment: ok, this is for reading in the same page, but not from the parent to the child

Comment: Nope, this is for reading in the page you receive form data

Comment: yes, that's what i try to said, sorry, but this is not what I need, I need to receive the data in the first tab, so, the problem is not read in jsp, it's return the first tab

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Not clear sorry i don't understand what do you want and what do you have